# Watir's ability to find element in iframe depends on previous code

Tags: ruby, iframe, watir

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new #:phantomjs (same with firefox)
@browser.window.maximize 

@browser.goto 'http://www.romnation.net/'

size = ['728', '90']
p @browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).length
@browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).each do |ifr|
    p ifr.img.src if ifr.img.present? # 1
end

size = ['160', '600']
p @browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).length
@browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).each do |ifr|
    p ifr.img.src if ifr.img.present?
end
```

This program will say that there are no iframes (160, 600) on a page (even though there are). If I don't search for (728, 90) iframes first, program always finds (160, 600) iframes. Further more, it happens only if I don't only search for (728, 90) iframes first, but if I search for images (line 1) in these iframes also.

Why on earth may that be? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug - https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/237
I have an open pull request that fixes it, but it is still waiting for full review:
https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/pull/286

Window#use helps because it returns the driver to the top-level browsing context.
It is essentially doing:
 
`@browser.driver.switch_to.default_content` 
or
 
`@browser.assert_exists`

Answer (score 0):

```
size = ['728', '90']
p @browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).length
@browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).each do |ifr|
    p ifr.img.src if ifr.img.present? # 1
end

@browser.window(:url => 'http://www.romnation.net/').use #__________new

size = ['160', '600']
p @browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).length
@browser.iframes(width: size[0], height: size[1]).each do |ifr|
    p ifr.img.src if ifr.img.present?
end
```

Switching to main window again with `@browser.window(:url => 'http://www.romnation.net/').use` helps.